# PHP Warning: ssh2_exec(): Failed setting DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive on remote end

Tags: php, environment-variables, ssh2-exec

I have written snippet to execute code in remote machine using `ssh2_exec`and command execution works fine . I want to set some environmental variables. But when I pass them as `ssh2_exec` params I'm getting this warning and the environmental variables are not getting set. Please advice

```
PHP Warning:  ssh2_exec(): Failed setting DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive on 
remote end in  Setup.php on line 405
```

My code

```
$env_vars = array(
    'DEBIAN_FRONTEND' => 'noninteractive'
);
$stream = ssh2_exec($con, escapeshellcmd($command), null , $env_vars);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work around

set environmental variables by using export command, along with command.

```
Eg: export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive; apt-get install -y mysql-server
```